# Sending to sign Document to CC member

Tags: echosign

I'm using the Adob sign API for document sign purpose.Once that document get sign adobe will share that document via Mail So My

Question is that I want to  share  that document with the CC member as well.

Is that Possible in API calling....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is in reference to the V5 version of Adobe Sign's REST API since this is the current latest version.

To meet your use case, you can specify the participants which you want to act as CCs in the transection while creating an agreement using POST /agreements API. These CCs will receive emails after every signing step of the agreement.

You should refer to the request body of [POST /agreements](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements/createAgreement) API to understand the format in which you can specify these CCs. To guide you further inside documentCreationInfo of POST /agreements request there is an attribute names "ccs", this accepts "," separated lists of CC emails.